# VBA Excel find function for currency formatted cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am not experienced in VBA coding at all and I have a seemingly simple question. I would like to create a click button macro which will find and select every currency formated cell which includes the euro symbol € or every currency formatted cell that has a sum above 0 within a specific column. At the moment this code :

```
Cells.Find(What:="€", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

is close to what I want to achieve (finds the € symbol) but it does not work on currency formatted cells which by default-automatically add the euro symbol to the sum..and is not defined to a specific column. 
If for example in my worksheet only some currency formatted cells have a € symbol (which I am looking for), then macro gives me a Run-time error 91..The same exactly search parameters work fine using the native excel search function.

See pictures attached 
Please kindly help it will help me a lot with my project =)

This doesnt work :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQqJp.jpg

This finds the euro symbol exactly as i would like my macro do.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM1lY.jpg

Comment: This `LookAt:=xlWhole` should be `LookAt:=xlPart`!

Comment: Your "native Excel search parameters" are **NOT** exactly the same.  In particular, the native parameters are **NOT** `lookat:=xlWhole`, and are **NOT** `lookin:=xlValues`.  Rather that dialog box is `lookat:=xlPart` and `lookin:=xlValues`.  Change your macro and you should be OK.

Comment: shrivallabha.redij i forgot to mention that i tried with LookAt:=xlPart but still getting the same Runtime error 91

Comment: Ron Rosenfeld i made the changes and still doesnt work  :(  .Please see the picture i reuploaded

Answer (score 2):

Part of your need.  This routine will `Select` all cells containing the euro symbol.  It will handle euros displayed by **formatting** as well as euros **included in the cell text.**

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, rFound As Range

    Set rFound = Nothing
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If InStr(1, r.Text, "€") > 0 Then
            If rFound Is Nothing Then
                Set rFound = r
            Else
                Set rFound = Union(rFound, r)
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then rFound.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Gary's Student than you very much for your time trying to help me. Your code selects all the cells within my worksheet which have the € symbol and also activates the first found cell. When i change the "ActiveSheet.UsedRange" with the range i want ActiveSheet.Range("H2:H200") it selects all the € symbol within my defined range and activates the first cell found . So far is good but how can i make it find and activate next € symbol within my predifed range every time i use the macro?

Comment: This does exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Test the following-

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Cells.Find(What:="€", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: To find the part,  LookAt:=xlPart

Comment: Gary's Student and Dy.Lee thank you for your answers but unfortunatelly it still does not find the euro symbol on currency format cells...only on general format  :(  . I tried also with LookAt:=xlPart